# CodeIgniter - How to route a controller with other name?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I have installed an authentication module named bit_auth in my codeIgniter.
I have a controller for that module named "bit_auth" so when calling functions on my controller my urls will be like this:

```
http://(mydomain.com)/bit_auth/
http://(mydomain.com)/bit_auth/edit_user/1
http://(mydomain.com)/bit_auth/activate/7b60a33408a9611d78ade9b3fba6efd4fa9eb0a9
```

Now **I want to route my `bit_auth` controller to be called from `http://(mydomain.com)/auth/...`.**
I have defined these routes in my "`config/routes.php`":

```php
$route['auth/(:any)'] = "bit_auth/$1";
$route['auth'] = "bit_auth";
```

It's working fine when I use: http://(mydomain.com)/auth/  
but ***it shows me 404 page not found error when opening links such as:
 
http://(mydomain.com)/auth/edit_user/1  

http://(mydomain.com)/auth/activate/7b60a33408a9611d78ade9b3fba6efd4fa9eb0a9***

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling and investigating I saw somewhere they where using another syntax for routing in CodeIgniter which was using ***[regular expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)*** directly rather than using codeigniter described patterns like *`(:any)`* or *`(:num)`* in its help. I just replaced **`(:any)`** with **`(.+)`** in my `config/routes.php` and now it is working perfect.

```
$route['auth/(.+)'] = "bit_auth/$1";
$route['auth'] = "bit_auth";
```

**Because in CodeIgniter `(:any)` and `(:num)` are not including `/`** and they are aliases for regular expression patterns of `([^\/]+)` and `(\d+)` so if you want to match rest of the link including any number of `/` you can use manual regular expression pattern `(.+)` which includes `/` in its pattern and will trigger for the all rest of URL.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using more params than are in the route you will have to do this:

```
$route['auth/(:any)/(:num)'] = "bit_auth/$1/$2";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for response, I tried your code and it works for both addresses in my question but it is not working everywhere, for example I have another link like this: http://(mydomain.com)/auth/activate/7b60a33408a9611d78ade9b3fba6efd4fa9eb0a9 which is showing error 404 page again.

Comment: In that case change `:num` to `:any`.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now but what about other links? I hope to be another way for including rest of links for example variable length of extra uri segments.

Comment: You'll have to add **another** line to your `routes.php` e.g. `$route['auth/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "bit_auth/$1/$2/$3";`